# What is the Python expression for calculating Lat/Long in Decimal Degrees in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser, calculate-values

I'm calculating 4 double fields for a polygon feature class (exploded, single-part features): `SquareFeet`, `Acreage`, `Lat`, and `Long`

I found the correct python expressions to calculate `SquareFeet` & `Acreage` using the **Calculate Field (Data Management)** tool.

For the `Lat` and `Long` fields, I've tried using `!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!` which calculates in either feet or meters depending on which unit is set on the data, but since I need the calculation in decimal degrees this isn't acceptable. And I've tried `!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y@DECIMALDEGREES!` to get the calculation in decimal degrees, but this expression just flat out doesn't return anything. I've tried setting the parser to PYTHON and PYTHON_9.3.

Does anyone know if there's a python expression to calculate latitude and longitude in decimal degrees?

(`!SHAPE.CENTROID.X@DECIMALDEGREES!` of course was used to try and calculate `Long`)

[image: Calculate Field tool]

Comment: Change the expression type to 'Python'. I'm not sure that capability was available in v9.3.

Comment: @Bjorn "PYTHON" is pre-9.3, "PYTHON_9.3" is 9.3 onwards.  Are you saying it was present before 9.3 but then removed?

Comment: I've tried both ways, and neither parser works, so it must be the expression that't not right

Comment: @geominded What version of ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: @Midavalo 10.3 using a professional or standard license

Comment: @geominded by "professional" license do you mean "Advanced"  or are you talking about ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: It is ***NOT*** possible to cast a Y value to latitude in isolation -- You need to deproject a vertex.

Comment: Perhaps set coordinate system of data frame to WGS, calculate geometry might give you an option you are after

Comment: @Vince can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that for some reason, the data has to be in a geographic coordinate system without a projection, and you can on-the-fly project into WGS84 (in the case in the code below) or NAD83 when calculating.

The code below ended up being a solution to calculating Lat/Long for polygons in decimal degrees:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inputData, "LAT", "arcpy.PointGeometry(!Shape.centroid!,!Shape.spatialReference!).projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)).firstPoint.Y","PYTHON_9.3","#")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(inputData, "LONG", "arcpy.PointGeometry(!Shape.centroid!,!Shape.spatialReference!).projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)).firstPoint.X","PYTHON_9.3","#")
```